# Ubuntu 16.04 does not use my AMD Radeon graphics card

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

i have a AMD Radeon R7 M360 graphics card in my notebook.
But Ubuntu does not use that Card.
Instead it looks like some onboard card or something

Hardinfo shows as my VGA compatible controller "Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520"

so it looks like some driver issues or something

Does anyone know what i can do, that the system uses my radeon graphics card?

Comment: 16.04 + AMD != good drivers unfortunately.

Comment: so i have to accept it? or are there soloutions?

Comment: Have you gone ahead and check Dash > Additional Drivers?

Comment: Additional Drivers shows an Unknown Device only